# как создать gulpfile.js?

Tags: javascript, frontend, gulp

Всем привет. Пытаюсь разобраться с gulp, но когда создаю файл gulpfile.js, то vs code пишет "файл с таким именем недопустимо для файла или папки". Если написать любое другое название файла, то тоже самое. Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]